# How can applying attribute class in line string according to their content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textarea` where I write some MVC Helpers and click `"process"` it applies class attribute helpers in this way.

Input:

```
<textarea name="message">
@Html.TextBox(m => m.TextTwo, new {@id="texttwo"})
@Html.TextBox(m => m.DataOne, new {@id="dataone"})
@Html.TextBox(m => m.NumberTwo, new {@id="numbertwo"})
@Html.TextBox(m => m.TextOne, new {@id="textone"})
@Html.TextBox(m => m.DataTwo, new {@id="datatwo"})
@Html.TextBox(m => m.NumberOne", new {@id="numberone"})
</textarea>

<button>process</button>
```

Need to apply the following rule of classes:

- The Helper **m.Text** the word that you would have to apply the attribute **@
  class = "text"**.
- The Helper **m.Number** that has the word would have to apply the attribute
  **@ class = "number"**.
- The Helper that has the word **m.Data** would have to apply the attribute **@
  class = "date"**.

An example of how the code would output in textarea

```
@Html.TextBox(m => m.TextTwo, new {@id="texttwo", @class="text"})
@Html.TextBox(m => m.DataOne, new {@id="dataone", @class="data"})
@Html.TextBox(m => m.NumberTwo, new {@id="numbertwo", @class="number"})
@Html.TextBox(m => m.TextOne, new {@id="textone", @class="text"})
@Html.TextBox(m => m.DataTwo, new {@id="datatwo", @class="data"})
@Html.TextBox(m => m.NumberOne", new {@id="numberone", @class="number"})
```

This is my javascript code:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    if ($('#output').length < 1) {
        $("body").append('<h2>Output</h2><textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>');
    }        



    $('#output').val(code);
});
```

**DEMO:** [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/LC5y3/1/)

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  Why would you put an `<input>` element inside a `<textarea>` ?

Comment: I am developing a simple patterning of code, I have an application that has thousands of Helpers and Views that follow the same structure as quoted, and need to automate this.